# Forms to create and update Mongoid array fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid, fields-for

I've been struggling to create a form for a Mongoid model that has an array field. I want my form to have on text box per entry in the array. If I'm creating a new record, the default will be one empty field (and some javascript to add new fields dynamically on the page).

I've searched around for a solution using fields_for but it seems that is more intended to handle the case where you have an array of objects/models and not the case I have, which is an array of strings.

I'm going to use the example of a person and a phone number.

```
class Person
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, :type => String
  field :phone_numbers, :type => Array
end
```

For the controller, just assume the typical controller but in the `new` method I initialized the phone_number array with one blank string.

Here's the form code:

```
  <%= form_for(@person) do |f| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :name %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :name %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :phone_numbers %><br />
      <% @person.phone_numbers.each do |phone_number| %>
        <%= text_field_tag "person[phone_numbers][]", phone_number %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

This all works fine. There are a few things that I don't like.

- The hardcoded name of the field in the text_field_tag call.
- Using text_field_tag instead of f.text_field
- Having the feeling like I should somehow be using fields_for instead of this

Does anybody have any better suggestions on how to implement this? Or would you consider this correct?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I agree with your concerns -

1. The hard-coded name of the field in the `text_field_tag` call.
2. Using text_field_tag instead of `f.text_field`
3. using `fields_for`

After doing some research found that first two concerns can be solved and probably also third can but haven't tried yet.

```
 <%= form_for(@person) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :phone_numbers %><br />
    <% @person.phone_numbers.each do |phone_number| %>
      <%= f.text_field :phone_numbers, :name => "#{f.object_name}[phone_numbers][]"%>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<%end%>
```

Another clean approach could be having form builder defined text_field and then having -

```
def text_field(attribute, *args)
  args.last.merge!(:name => "#{object_name}[#{attribute}][]") if args.last && args.last.is_a?(Hash) && args.last.delete(:array)
  super(attribute, args)
end

<% @person.phone_numbers.each do |phone_number| %>
  <%= f.text_field :phone_numbers, :array => true%>
<% end %>
```

[You can find more information here](http://www.funonrails.com/2012/01/mongoid-embededin-and-array-field.html)

Comment: In your first example it's : `f.text_field :phone_numbers, :name => "#{f.object_name}[phone_numbers][]"` Can you change this typo ?

Comment: This solution is fine but you also have to set the value of each phone number : In your code, each `phone_numbers[]` field has the full `@person.phone_numbers` Array as value. You have to change to this: `f.text_field :phone_numbers, :name => "#{f.object_name}[phone_numbers][]", :value => phone_number`. In my case, I now have to add new fields with cocoon, which will surely be another problem since it's based on associations...

Answer (score 3):

You could work with embeds_many:

```
class Person
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name
  embeds_many :phone_numbers
end

class PhoneNumber
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :number
  embedded_in :person
end
```

And then, within your view, you could use:

```
<%= form_for(@person) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <%= @person.phone_numbers.each do |phone_number| %>
    <%= f.fields_for phone_number do |p| %>
      <div class="field">
        <%= p.label :number %><br />
        <%= p.text_field :number %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I'm actually trying to avoid this. This would be an acceptable solution if the PhoneNumber model had more than one field. The example I chose was the closest analogy without confusing things. In my situation there would be zero need to have an extra PhoneNumber model even if it were embedded.

Comment: I understand. However, whenever you use fields_for, it expects an object with accessors for the attributes and some other methods like new_record? Basically speaking, the object hat to implement the ActiveModel interface.

Comment: Thanks, given that this is the case, I cannot use fields_for in this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

According to a comment posted mosch in a comment to his own solution:

> whenever you use fields_for, it expects an object with accessors for the attributes and some other methods like new_record? Basically speaking, the object hat to implement the ActiveModel interface.

The answer to my question is that there is not a better way unless I create another model for the phone nubmers, like was mosch suggested.

Answer (score 0):

The second div should be like the following

```
<div class="field"><%= f.fields_for :phone_numbers do | phone | %>
 <%= phone.text_field "phone_numer[]" %><% end %></div>
```